# Setting Regular Time Interval (boolean) value of an ApplicationPool using PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, iis

**What I need**

Is to automatically set the value marked in yellow to false using PowerShell:

[image]

*That's when doing right-click Advanced Settings on the ApplicationPool.*

I need it for an Octopus post-deploy script.

**What I don't need**

I don't need the `Regular Time Interval (minutes)`, that's already covered by:

```
$AppPool.recycling.periodicRestart.time = ( [TimeSpan]::FromMinutes($desiredValue))
```

**What I know**

Different to many of the other values, `Regular Time Interval` is not in the `applicationHost.config` file. I'm sure because:

> 1. I can't find anything like the text in the host file.
> 2. Setting the value through IIS does not update the file

So I can't use the host config to look up the structure (like I have with other values).

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information can be read from the `Recycling.LogEventOnRecycle` property of the app pool object returned by `Get-IISAppPool`, but weirdly, changes to that don't seem to persist.

To make the changes stick, we need a different route. First, we'll import the IIS administration module, which creates a pseudo-drive containing IIS objects.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
```

Then we move to the app pool in question.

```
cd "IIS:\AppPools\$name"
```

(Assuming `$name` is the name of your app pool.) Now we get the part of the configuration concerning recycling.

```
$cfg = Get-ItemProperty . 'recycling'
```

This value is a comma-separated list of the events that cause an event to be generated. We remove `Time`, the one corresponding to the GUI element you highlighted.

```
$cfg.logEventOnRecycle = ($cfg.logEventOnRecycle -split ',' | ? {$_ -ne 'Time'}) -join ','
```

Finally we commit the changed configuration section.

```
Set-ItemProperty . 'recycling' $cfg
```

Consulting the IIS management GUI shows that this does indeed save our choice.

Note to avoid confusion from other future readers: turning this particular option off does not disable periodic recycles. Rather, it removes the log entry generated when the recycle happens. To disable periodic restarts, set the Regular Time Interval setting to zero.

Comment: You need to be in elevated (admin) rights mode to run, but this works!

Comment: I was actually very close, the only (fundamental) difference is that I saved on item level (not property): `$AppPool | Set-Item -Verbose`, which works for all other properties I'm setting, but apparently not for `logEventOnRecycle`.